# cakephp why can't I have an admin route and a superuser route?

Tags: cakephp

In core.php I can define

```
Configure::write('Routing.admin', 'admin');
```

and /admin/controller/index will work.

but if I define both

```
Configure::write('Routing.admin', 'admin');
Configure::write('Routing.superuser', 'superuser');
```

and try to look at /superuser/blah/index/ instead of it saying the controller doesn't exist it says

```
Error: SuperuserController could not be found.
```

instead of saying

```
Error: BlahController could not be found.
```

When I first read the documentation I was under the impression I could run both routes, and not just one or the other. Is there something more I need to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe they are working on this for CakePHP 1.3, but for now, we have to cheat to accomplish additional routing.  This is the method I've used in the past.

```
// SuperUser Routing
Router::connect('/superuser/:controller',
    array('prefix' => 'superuser', 'superuser' => true));
Router::connect('/superuser/:controller/:action/*',
    array('prefix' => 'superuser', 'superuser' => true));
```

There were some issues generating URLs using the `array('controller' => ...)` method, but I haven't touched that project in a few months, so I can't remember all the caveats with it.  This should at least give you a starting point though.

The [CakePHP document explains this some](http://book.cakephp.org/view/544/Prefix-Routing).  The relevant section starts about halfway in talking about multiple prefixes.

Comment: That works. I'll have to keep an eye out for those issues you mentioned.

Comment: I think it had to do with explicitly needing to set 'prefix' => false or something like that when you were using the route and using an array for the URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Jason's trick, and having trouble with generating URLs using the array('controller' => ...) syntax, then put this in your appcontroller:

`if (isset($this->params['prefix']) && $this->params['prefix'] == 'superuser') {
     Configure::write('Routing.admin', 'superuser');

}`

This forces the appcontroller to use the correct admin prefix, which in this case is "superuser".